# Simplest way to make generic logging in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, but still

```
public class Logging
{ 
    public static int Write(params object[] items)
    {
        return Console.Write(items);
    }
}
```

seems just ok, but does not work.
Well it is not obvious that all instances or Write are defined in compile time, but they are.

If i call

```
Logging.Write("Hello world");
```

i got string

```
System.Object[]
```

as response

Comment: When you say it "does not work" can you elaborate?

Comment: What is your problem? "Does not work" is no adequate error description.

Comment: I see that your problem is not about logging but about ConsoleWriteline and dtb already answered yuor question. If you really want to roll your own logging, please consider using a mature LoggingFramework (log4Net, NLog) or in case you want to exchange the logging framework, a Logging abstraction (CommonLogging: http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. There is no overload of the [Console.Write method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write.aspx) that does not return `void` (e.g., `int`).
2. There is no overload of the [Console.Write method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write.aspx) that takes an array of `object`. The overload matching is the one taking a single `object` which converts the `object` to `string` by invoking the [ToString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx). The [ToString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) returns `"System.Object[]"` for an array of `object`.

---

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
public class Logging
{ 
    public static void Write(params object[] items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", items));
    }
}
```

*Example:*

```
int x = 42;
Logging.Write("The value of x is", x);
```

*Output:*

```
The value of x is 42
```

Comment: Sorry for late response but I want that my function that takes any number and any type of arguments passes arguments to other function. I am able to make this happen in C, C++ , Python and even in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not what your question is about, but i would suggest using a logging library, i love NLog, then there is Log4Net there are more but those are those i know about!